# How to recover from failed installment of codelite

Tags: ubuntu

My system initially is ubuntu 12.04. I installed codelite yesterday by running "apt-get install codelite", it worked fine. I noticed that it is not the latest version and tried installing the latest manually, but this introduced problem.

I followed the instruction from codelite web page:

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ trusty universe'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codelite
```

But I got dependency error just like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856727/error-while-installing-codelite-ide-in-ubuntu).

I then tried several suggestions, the latest is [Howto install the latest codelite in Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-install-the-latest-codelite-in-ubuntu). But I missed the note about "amd64" and "i386" initially and after I corrected, there still problem.

Anyway, I give up installing the latest version at this point, but I found that I cannot go back now - I uninstalled codelite in the beginning - when I run "apt-get install codelite" again, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codelite : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not installable
            Depends: libwxbase3.0-0 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Could you point me how I can recover from this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of [Howto install the latest codelite in Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-install-the-latest-codelite-in-ubuntu). I have tested the latest codelite on Trusty.

If you still have issues with codelite, remove like so: `sudo apt-get purge codelite`

Note that the dependencies links are dead. But, I managed to install it anyway:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE6fg.png]

Codelite 6.1 on Ubuntu Trusty Thar 14.04. 
Image from: [Howto install the latest codelite in Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-install-the-latest-codelite-in-ubuntu)

Install like so:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codelite wxcrafter
```

Feel free to contact me here, or on my website, for any issues you may have.

**Source**:

- [Howto install the latest codelite in Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-install-the-latest-codelite-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Do you happen to know why the version in the repo is still 5.4 and not 7.0 for ubuntu "precise"?

Comment: @nbubis at the moment, no idea.

Comment: O.P. mentions "amd64" and "i386" but what about my arm-based system?  how do I build?  The instructions on CodeLite's site do not work (cmake has errors such as "failed to find gtk", "libssh not found", etc even though i have those packages installed